# Can I generate foo_= and foo accessors from setFoo and getFoo?

Tags: scala

I'm getting started with using Scala on Android and a lot of the accessor methods are standard JavaBeans accessors, e.g. `setTitle(...)` and `getTitle()`. It's a lot nicer to use the `title_=` and `title` methods in scala, so I can write code like:

```
button.title = "Foo"
```

Is there any way to automatically map these *from* JavaBeans-style accessors, maybe using the `Dynamic` trait?

Comment: +1 I'd love to hear if there is a mechanism for this as well.  My hunch says no.

Comment: If I'm willing to turn on -experimental, I think this can be done by mixing in a trait that extends `Dynamic` and uses reflection `applyDynamic` to convert one to the other. Reflection probably creates an undesirable amount of overhead on Android, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Dynamic *would* work, except it is not presently supported with syntactic sugar. Also, it would return `AnyRef` since there's no way to pass what the expected return type is.

Of course, you can simply use pimp my library to add appropriate Scala-style getters and setters.

Comment: PML is definitely my second option. Good point about typing - that would kind of kill the convenience of having nicer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is supported on Android, but you can use `@BeanProperty`:

```
class X {
  @scala.reflect.BeanProperty
  var y:String = _
}

val x = new X()
x.setY("Test")
println(x.getY) //--> Test
```

There are more annotations for Bean support, e.g. `@BooleanBeanProperty` and `@BeanInfo`.

Comment: Right, I know about BeanProperty - I'm looking for the other way around, i.e. I want to treat getFoo/setFoo as foo/foo_=

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your question. AFAIK there isn't a built-in solution for that direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the dynamic trait will help you. I guess you need reflection to use the methods and they will not be discoverable through reflection.

I think you're best chance is to create a scala compiler plugin (see http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140 and http://www.sts.tu-harburg.de/people/mi.garcia/ScalaCompilerCorner/).

Comment: Why wouldn't they be discoverable through reflection?

Comment: In the applyDynamic method you are free to accept or reject any call at any time, but you don't have an interface there to list which methods you accept.